# Which is used more / is more natural in speech? 突然 or どっと?

Tags: spoken-language

As far as the translation of the word 'suddenly' my dictionary has these two^. Are they any different or is one more common than the other?
ありがとう

Comment: 「急に」 also means "suddenly" and is very common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

突然 is more *common*, because its meaning is broader than that of どっと.
突然 is just "suddenly." どっと does have meaning of suddenness, but **usage of どっと is limited to those 3 situation**, according to [Digital Daijirin](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/159419/meaning/m0u/).

> 1. Lots of people letting out their voice at the same time.
> 2. Lots of people / things coming at one time.
> 3. Becoming (seriously) ill in a short time.

We use どっと like this:

> 1. 観客{かんきゃく}が**どっと**笑{わら}いだす (The audience **bursts into laughter**)
> 2. 人々が**どっと**押{お}し寄{よ}せる (The crowd **surges forward**)
> 3. **どっと**病{やまい}が重{おも}くなる (**Become seriously ill suddenly**.) (sentence from the reference)

All of which can be also said, using 突然 instead of どっと:

> 1. 観客が**突然**笑いだす
> 2. 人々が**突然**押し寄せる
> 3. **突然**病が重くなる

But, this is **not true for the converse**. Saying:

> **[x]** パソコンがどっと壊{こわ}れる

instead of パソコンが突然壊れる (the PC suddenly breaks down) is weird.

---

<strike>I think どっと came from manga - under those 3 situation, I see onomatopoeias "どっ" "ドッ" being used. どっ+と(`particle` indicating how an action is done.)</strike>

snaliboat pointed out that どっと being used way back in 1220s. In 金刀比羅本保元, there's a sentence that goes:

> 西の河原に時をどっと作ること三ヶ度なり

So どっと existed from the past. I'm figuring out what this means, though.

Comment: It seems どっと was in use 800 years ago, so I suppose it can't have come from manga.

Comment: @snailboat Really?! In what work or something can it be found?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N8O0h.jpg

Comment: Thanks~ I'll dig into that. I'll edit my answer as well.